# VueJS prevent form submission on submit and submit the form on keyup

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, vue.js

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/searchuser" method="POST" @submit.prevent="onSubmit(inputValue)">
   <div class="field">
      <label class="label">Name</label>
      <div class="control">
         <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" v-model="inputValue" @keyup="onKeyUp" @blur="inputFocused = false">
         <ul v-if="inputFocused">
            <li v-for="value in values"><a class="panel-block is-primary" :href="value.link">@{{value.title}}</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

And in my JavaScript, I have two methods onSubmit and onKeyPress:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
      inputFocused: false,
      values: [
        { title: "facebook", link: "http://facebook.com" },
        { title: "twitter", link: "http://twitter.com" },
        { title: "gplus", link: "http://plus.google.com" },
        { title: "youtube", link: "http://youtube.com" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onKeyUp: function() {
      document.forms["myForm"].submit();
      this.inputFocused = true;
    },
    onSubmit: function(inputval) {
      console.log(inputval);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when the user presses a key, I want the form to be submitted but I don't want the page to be redirected to `/searchuser` route. But as soon as I press a key, the page gets redirected even though I am using the `prevent` modifier to prevent the submission. How do I prevent it from being redirected and submit it on keyup/keydown only? My goal is to perform an ajax call through `onSubmit` by sending the `inputval` to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Vue is not overriding the DOM default behavior, if you decide to
  access the DOM API directly while bypassing vue mechanics (e.g.
  `document.forms`)
- If you want to submit a form without the redirection, you have to do
  ajax request.
- you have to use `axios` (my personal choice). because you are trying to submit the form directly ...in order to keep up with the default form submission data format, **I assume** you need to sereialize the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded format`. [check the docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format).

see the code:

**onKeyUp method:**

```
onKeyUp: function() {
  axios.post("/searchuser", qs.stringify({ inputValue: inputValue }));
  this.inputFocused = true;
},
```

Remember to add `axios` and `qs` to your dependencies using npm, and import them on the file.